# How to use Google translate node library in angular 4

Tags: node.js, angular, google-translate, google-translation-api

I want to use google translate library in my angular 4 app. I didn't saw any documentation. So i am working on rest api. With rest API i am getting below response. when i use same url in postman it is working fine.

app.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpRequest , HttpHeaders, HttpParams} from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable()
export class HttpService {

    userData : any;

    constructor(public http: HttpClient) {}

    /*  First parameter is url.
        second is object of request params.
        Don't pass 2nd paramater if not required.
    */
    get<T>(url, requestParams?:Object) {
        let options = {};
        options = this.getOptions(requestParams);
        return this.http.get<T>(url,options);
    }

    /*  First parameter is url.
        second is request body. Pass atleast null if no body for your request.
        Third is request parameters.
        Don't pass 3rd paramater if not required.
    */
    post<T>(url, postBody: any, requsetParams?: Object) {
        let options = {};
        options = this.getOptions(requsetParams);
        return this.http.post<T>(url,postBody, options);
    }

    /*  First parameter is url.
        second is object of request params.
        Don't pass 2nd paramater if not required.
    */
    delete(url, requestParams?: Object) {
        let options = {};
        options = this.getOptions(requestParams);
        return this.http.delete(url, options);
    }

    /*  First parameter is url.
        second is request body. Pass atleast null if no body for your request.
        Third is request parameters.
        Don't pass 3rd paramater if not required.
    */
    put(url, putData, requsetParams?: Object) {
        let options = this.getOptions(requsetParams);
        return this.http.put(url, putData, options);
    }

    getOptions(requestParams?: Object) {

        let options = {};

        this.userData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("currentUser"));
        if(this.userData !== null) {
            let headers = new HttpHeaders({
                'authorization': 'Bearer ' + this.userData.token
            })
            options['headers'] = headers;
        }

        if(requestParams !== undefined) {
            let httpParams = new HttpParams();
            Object.keys(requestParams).forEach(function (key) {
                httpParams = httpParams.append(key, requestParams[key]);
            });

            options['params'] = httpParams;
        }

        return options;
    }

}
```

myservice.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpService } from '../http.service';
import { TranslateResponse } from './model/translate-response';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { DetectLanguageResponse } from './model/detect-language-response';

const googleTranlateApiURL: string = 'https://translation.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2';
const googleTranlateApiKey: string = '';
const googleTranlateApiFormat: string = 'text';


@Injectable()
export class GoogleTranslateService {



  constructor(private httpService: HttpService) { }

  translate(q: string, target: string, source: string): Observable<TranslateResponse> {
    return this.httpService.post<TranslateResponse>(`${googleTranlateApiURL}?q=${q}&target=${target}&source=${source}&key=${googleTranlateApiKey}`, {});
  }

  detect(q: string): Observable<DetectLanguageResponse> {
    return this.httpService.post<DetectLanguageResponse>(`${googleTranlateApiURL}/detect?q=${q}&key=${googleTranlateApiKey}`, {});
  }
}
```

response

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 401,
    "message": "Request had invalid authentication credentials. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Request had invalid authentication credentials.",
        "reason": "authError"
      }
    ],
    "status": "UNAUTHENTICATED"
  }
```

Any one can help me what wrong i am doing and how i can use plain nodejs library in angular 4

https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/reference/libraries

Comment: some code please? And it looks like you don't have valid credentials. You need to show something so people can reproduce it

Comment: @ChauTran, updated with code

Comment: Does not look like you're appending the APIKey in your POST Url as `googleTranlateApiKey` is an empty string?

Comment: I removed my key to post question. i have key in my application

Comment: Right my bad. This is hard to debug as I never ran into problems like this. Possibly, could you move your `googleTranslate` variables inside of the Class and use `this.`?

Comment: I saw my chrome developer tool. It is sending api key.

Comment: Does your request have an `Authorization: Bearer token`? Is that token the API Key or the User's JWT Token?

Comment: Yes my request have Authorization: Bearer token

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169186/discussion-between-chau-tran-and-user-27).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem lies in the `Authorization` headers being sent along with the request to `Google Translate API`.

`Google Translate API` will look for an `Authorization` header in the request headers and will extract the value from it to use as the `API Key`. Having the `Authorization` header, `Google Translate API` will ignore the `key` queryParameter in the request URL.

Either you need to do some logic to `NOT` appending `Authorization` on `POST` to the API or use the `API Key` as the `Authorization` header instead of the `User's Token`.